# Django: I am unable to get Django to autocreate an autofield

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

I am calling `BORROWER.objects.create(ssn=Ssn, bname=Name, address=Address, phone=Phone)` from `views.py` to create an entry in my sqlite database. This is my models.py file with the relevant function.

```
class BORROWER(models.Model):
card_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, max_length=7)
ssn = models.CharField(max_length=11)
bname = models.CharField(max_length=71)
address = models.CharField(max_length=79)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.card_id)
```

The database entry is successfully created. However, since I am not specifying a value for the `card_id` field, the value stays as `(<django.db.models.fields.AutoField>,)` instead of an actual key. When I try to specify a value for `card_id` it says something about unexpected argument. Am I calling the create function incorrectly?

Edit: The comma is not there in the original code, but I will try with the suggested edits

Comment: You have a trailing comma at the end of that line, which wraps the `AutoField` in a singleton tuple.

Comment: Sorry, the comma is not there in the original code, I tested without the comma and the issue persists. I will try again to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove comma at the end of the `card_id` and don't use `max_length` with `AutoFiled` ..

```
class BORROWER(models.Model):
card_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
ssn = models.CharField(max_length=11)
bname = models.CharField(max_length=71)
address = models.CharField(max_length=79)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.card_id)
```

Comment: Thank you, removing max_length seemed to have fixed it!